# Need help aligning radio buttons in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, alignment, radiobuttonfor

I am having a hard time aligning radio Buttons to the left in MVC 4 template using RadioButtonFor.

For some reason they are placed in the middle,  abd it only happens with radio buttons below is a picture:

I have tried to float the div but it did not work .

I also tried to add css class to radio button helper but I got an overload error for the function RadioButtonFor

I even tried to put it into a table

Please advice, here is my code

```
<div class="editor-field"  >
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isChildTakingMedicine, true, new { @onchange = "showTextBox()" }) YES<br />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isChildTakingMedicine, false, new { @onchange = "showTextBox()" }) NO
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.isChildTakingMedicine)
     </td> 
</tr>
</table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was the width of the radio button to wide, the default css gives a large width to  all input tag.

Added the following CSS to fix it:

```
input[type="radio"]  
{
       width: 20px;   
}
```

Comment: thnx for the help... i was trying with input[type="radiobutton"] .. :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it took me longer than expected to arrive at the correct structure for my bootstrap'd situation. I wanted to save others the pain and I hope this layout can help. The data model, in my case, was simply an integer called Status.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Status</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="radio-inline"><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, 1) Acknowledged </label></div>
            <div class="radio-inline"><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, 2) In Progress </label></div>
            <div class="radio-inline"><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, 3) Closed/Fixed </label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this necessarily answers your question, but I thought this may be helpful information for anyone having a similar issue:

I have a table with rows and columns of radio buttons (user is meant to select 1 of the radio buttons in each row).  The radio buttons were not lining up with the row or column header texts.  Guess what fixed it - adding a border to the table!  I tried all sorts of things first, using align and valign, or align within style...that kind of thing.  I took all that off and just set "border=1" for the table.  Voila - radio buttons are all left aligned with the header text!

Comment: If you do not want column borders to be visible, you can also use "border=0".  This will have the same effect without showing lines in between columns.